# Trouble passing associative array from javascript to php and insert it into mysql database through prepared statements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, prepared-statement

http://jsfiddle.net/kqd7m5nb/

Just click on the insert data button, notice an alert box. This is an associative array. These are the values I want to pass into my php file.

In The php file, I get a Post value containing all the data I passed from my ajax data. I decoded It using json_decode. The data is now extracted as a php array of type stdClass. And I am now using prepared statements to insert all of the php array through the for loop statement.

Using Xdebug, the arrow stops inside the for loop of the php file. And after that, nothing gets inserted into my database. I also noticed when evaluating the 'count($value)' on php on xdebug, it returns 1 instead of 3. And evaluating $value[0]->fname in XDEBUG also returns an error.

sample.js

```
$('#ajax').click(function() {
        var values = $('#mytable tbody tr').map(function() {
            return {
                fname : $('td:eq(0)',this).text(),
                lname : $('td:eq(1)',this).text(),
                point : parseInt($('td:eq(2)',this).text())
            }
        }); 
        var valuesDebug = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            valuesDebug += " " + values[i]["fname"] + " " + values[i]["lname"] + " " + values[i]["point"] + "\n";
        }
        alert(valuesDebug);
        var valueStringed = JSON.stringify(values);
        $.ajax({
            "type":"POST",
            "url":"insertData.php",
            "data":{value : valueStringed},
            "success":function(data){
                alert('Done inserting the current table values');
            }
        });
    });
```

insertData.php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['value']))
    {
        $value = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['value']));
    }
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","test");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") "     . $mysqli->connect_error;  
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO team VALUES (NULL,?, ?, ?)"); //NULL is auto increment primary key id
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $fname, $lname, $point);

    if (count($value) > 0)
    {
        for( $i = 0 ;$i < count($value);$i++){
            $fname = $value[$i]->fname;
            $lname = $value[$i]->lname;
            $point = $value[$i]->point;
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: can you post the output of `print_r($_POST)` so I can replicate?

Answer (score 0):

At a glance you need to be doing:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $fname, $lname, $point);
```

**in** your for loop as your **defining** them in the loop, if you do it above as you have - the variables are undefined.

So try:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO team VALUES (NULL,?, ?, ?)");

if (count($value) > 0)
{
    for( $i = 0 ;$i < count($value);$i++){

        $fname = $value[$i]->fname;
        $lname = $value[$i]->lname;
        $point = $value[$i]->point;

        $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $fname, $lname, $point);
        $stmt->execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you have more than one issue :(

Answer (score 0):

This code now works.

Please see my original javascript code.
It seems on this part I added an array valuesDebug and copied the contents from the values array through the push method. I don't know how exactly why this works. Is there a way to make this shorter?

BTW The first line is the row cell contents of my table being converted into the values array.

```
    var values = $('#mytable tbody tr').map(function() {
        return {
            fname : $('td:eq(0)',this).text(),
            lname : $('td:eq(1)',this).text(),
            point : parseInt($('td:eq(2)',this).text())
        }
    });         
   var valuesDebug = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        valuesDebug.push({fname: values[i]["fname"],lname: values[i]["lname"],point: values[i]["point"]});
    }

    var valueStringed = JSON.stringify(valuesDebug);
    // passes valueStringed into ajax ...
```